# Accessing nested variable variables in Ansible

Tags: ansible

Here is my `group_vars/all` file:

```
app_env: staging

staging:
  app_a:
    db_host: localhost
  app_b:
    db_host: localhost
production:
  app_a:
    db_host: app_a-db.example.net
  app_b:
    db_host: app_b-db.example.com
```

If `app_env` environment has to be production, I overwrite this via inventory variables. This way, all deployments are staging unless you make them production explicitly.

So, when I want to print the variable in a playbook, I can do

```
---
  - debug: var={{app_env}}.app_a.db_host
```

This works!

But how can I access the variable in another module, i.e. `lineinfile`?

Some Examples that didn't work out:

```
- lineinfile: dest=/etc/profile line='export APP_A_DB_HOST="{{ app_env.app_a.db_host }}"'
- lineinfile: dest=/etc/profile line='export APP_A_DB_HOST="{{ app_env[app_a][db_host] }}"'
- lineinfile: dest=/etc/profile line='export APP_A_DB_HOST="{{ {{app_env}}.app_a.db_host }}"'
```

Working solutions would be using the `set_fact` module (double lines of code, not really smart) or including different variable files, depending on `app_env`.

But I really would like to know if there's a notation to access nested variable variables ;)

Answer (score 24):

You would make your life easier with your 'environment dict' not being at the root, like so:

```
app_env: staging

app_environments:
  staging:
    app_a:
      db_host: localhost
    app_b:
      db_host: localhost
  production:
    app_a:
      db_host: app_a-db.example.net
    app_b:
      db_host: app_b-db.example.com
```

Then, you should be able to use `{{app_environments[app_env].app_a.db_host}}` or `{{app_environments[app_env]['app_a']['db_host']}}` everywhere (Jinja templates, tasks).

Watch out for too much "nestiness" though !